# ios lazytableimages in Storyboard

Tags: ios

How to convert iphone lazytableimages from .xib file to using storyboard?  or any sample code using storyboard which are similiar to lazytableimages. The source code from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where the controller's view comes from, be it xib, code or storyboard. The code of the controller does not change in that example's case, just make sure to put scene on storyboard, set it's view controller class and connect all the outlets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have transfer to storyboard successfullly. But the image are not display from the screen for initial load until i scroll down and scroll up again then only display the image. If scroll down to load the new record it can display image. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing reloadData or reloadRowsAt... somewhere. Post your view controller code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "MasterListViewController.h"
#import "AppRecord.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "ParseOperation.h"

#define kCustomRowHeight    60.0
#define kCustomRowCount     7

static NSString *const TopPaidAppsFeed =
@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/toppaidapplications/limit=75/xml";

@interface MasterListViewController ()
- (void)startIconDownload:(AppRecord *)appRecord forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation MasterListViewController

@synthesize entries;
@synthesize imageDownloadsInProgress;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageDownloadsInProgress = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = kCustomRowHeight;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    NSArray *allDownloads = [self.imageDownloadsInProgress allValues];
    [allDownloads makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(cancelDownload)];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int count = [entries count];

    if (count == 0)
    {
        return kCustomRowCount;
    }
    return count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // customize the appearance of table view cells
    //
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LazyTableCell";
    static NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell";

    // add a placeholder cell while waiting on table data
    int nodeCount = [self.entries count];

    //NSLog(@"RootViewController - nodeCount is %d",nodeCount);

    if (nodeCount == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                           reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Loading…";

        return cell;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // Leave cells empty if there's no data yet
    if (nodeCount > 0)
    {
        // Set up the cell...
        AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = appRecord.appName;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = appRecord.artist;

        // Only load cached images; defer new downloads until scrolling ends
        if (!appRecord.appIcon)
        {
            if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO)
            {
                [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
            // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image = appRecord.appIcon;
        }

    }

    return cell;
}


- (void)startIconDownload:(AppRecord *)appRecord forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    IconDownloader *iconDownloader = [imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (iconDownloader == nil)
    {
        iconDownloader = [[IconDownloader alloc] init];
        iconDownloader.appRecord = appRecord;
        iconDownloader.indexPathInTableView = indexPath;
        iconDownloader.delegate = self;
        [imageDownloadsInProgress setObject:iconDownloader forKey:indexPath];
        [iconDownloader startDownload];
    }
}

- (void)loadImagesForOnscreenRows
{
    if ([self.entries count] > 0)
    {
        NSArray *visiblePaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
        for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)
        {
            AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            if (!appRecord.appIcon) // avoid the app icon download if the app already has an icon
            {
                [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
        }
    }
}

// called by our ImageDownloader when an icon is ready to be displayed
- (void)appImageDidLoad:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    IconDownloader *iconDownloader = [imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (iconDownloader != nil)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:iconDownloader.indexPathInTableView];

        // Display the newly loaded image
        cell.imageView.image = iconDownloader.appRecord.appIcon;
    }

    // Remove the IconDownloader from the in progress list.
    // This will result in it being deallocated.
    [imageDownloadsInProgress removeObjectForKey:indexPath];
}


// Load images for all onscreen rows when scrolling is finished
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
    {
        [self loadImagesForOnscreenRows];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self loadImagesForOnscreenRows];
}

@end
```